# Spring integration - how to figure out that processing is finished

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have following flow defined in spring integration:

1. read and remove message (with web service request) from the given directory
2. transform it to string
3. send web service request with this message

The process definition looks like

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(inboundAdapter(getDirectory()))
            .transform(fileToString())
            .handle(sendRequestToWS)
            .get();
```

The number of messages in the given directory is fixed and I would like to inform user when all messages has been processes.

Do you have any idea how can I figure out that flow "has been finished"?

`FileReadingMessageSource` returns null when there is no more files in directory. So do I need custom implementation of `FileReadingMessageSource` which will send different message when directory is empty or maybe there is a better solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing `FileReadingMessageSource` to detect the null would work; or you could add a custom message source advice to the poller - see [Smart polling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

The smart poller would work for people using XML configuration too, where it's not so easy to use a custom `MessageSource`.

Comment: Custom `FileReadingMessageSource` works fine, thanks.